# RazorPay: getting CORS error in fetchPayment REST API

Tags: javascript, razorpay

I am able to integrate **RazorPay** in my application. After successful payment I am trying to call RazorPay REST API **fetchPayment** to get the complete detail of transaction but facing below error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_Fxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I tried with passing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' in header but still not working.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: Any solutions yet @DheerajChouhan